# would 2 GCM enabled App issued same id or not

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

What would happen if 2 different apps installed on 1 single device uses GCM service would both of them assigned same GCM client id or different client id.If different id then how server of first installed app know the user installs other app using GCM service then that server have to update the new id accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID identifies a particular app on a particular device, so the IDs of two apps will be different. You can use each ID to send a push notification to the specific app. In other words, you don't address a push notification to a device but to a specific app on a specific device.

> [Instance ID provides a unique ID per instance of your apps.](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/)